# Как убрать черную обводку div, обернутого в a, в Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Имеются карточки, кликнув по которым можно куда-то перейти по ссылке. Разметка выглядит следующим образом:

```
<a href="url">
  <div>text</div>
</a>
```

У ссылки изначально следующие стили:

```
outline: 0;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
```

У внутреннего div'a такие стили:

```
...
border: 1px solid grey;
...
```

Проще некуда, но в safari, при клике по карточке (посещении ссылки), обводка блока становится черным. Выглядит это примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда как в chrome все работает нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал задавать/обнулять/переопределять свойства в псевдоклассах `:link`, `:active`, `:visited`, например:

```
a:visited {
 color: любой цвет; // меняется только цвет внутреннего текста, обводка остается неизменной
 border: none; // border: 0; border: 1px solid transparent;
 outline: 0; // outline: none;
}
```

Также пытался приоритизировать с помощью `!important`. Все безуспешно

В веб инспекторе safari все выглядит так, как будто цвет указывается только для верхнего бордера карточки..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если подскажете в какую сторону смотреть, буду очень признателен, потому что на данный момент я в тупике. Не удивлюсь, если решение проблемы лежит на поверхности..

Comment: смотреть в сторону [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) Поставьте none вместо 0, если не поможет, повесьте его на *: `*{outline: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит тогда, когда элемент получает фокус. Пропишите ему в css файле onfocus, где нет границы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1178017/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0

Comment: Ссылка на эту ж проблему, с которой столкнулся я

Comment: Если считаете, что проблема та же, почему не предложили тот вопрос в качестве дубликата?